Circular definition of continuity
When evaluating limits, it's tempting to just plug in the approach value into the function to get the answer. For example, if $f(x) = x^2$ and we need to solve $\lim_{x \to 2}(f(x))$ then we want to just take $f(2)$ which gets us $2^2$ which gets us $4$.
However, we first need to prove that $f$ is continuous at $2$ before we can do that. And in order to do that, we need to show that $\lim_{x \to 2}(f(x)) = f(2)$. And in order to evaluate that limit, we need to show that $f$ is continuous at $2$. So we end up with a circular definition of continuity.
In precalculus (or "Advanced Integrated Math 3" in my case), we did learn about the concept of continuity but without any rigorous definition. We would just kind of look at the graph and use our intuition to determine where the function is continuous and where it is discontinuous. Though that's not really a reliable way to determine continuity, since we can only plot finitely many points of a function on a graph, even with our best technology. How am I supposed to know that, in the tiny space between two of those points, the function isn't discontinuous?

In some cases, the function limit existing at a point doesn’t necessarily mean that the function is continuous at that point. However, that does mean we can manipulate the function terms to get rid of the discontinuity, and then your statements would be true.

I didn't mean to claim that the function is continuous at a point if it's limit exists. I meant that the function is continuous at a point if it's limit at the point is equal to the function value at that point.

The simple answer is that you can't know. And this is probably what I despise most about the way pre-university calculus is taught.
But a rather simple way to get continuity for a huge class of functions very quickly without $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ is the following: First, you have to believe me that the identity $f(x) = x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. I think that this is not an unreasonable demand. And you would have to teach the students the triangle inequality.
Then the product of two continuous functions $f, g$ is continuous, if you accept that that continuous functions are bounded (by some $M$) in a small environment around the continuous point $x$. Then:
$$
0 \leq \lvert (fg)(x) - (fg)(y) \rvert \leq  \lvert f(x) \rvert \lvert g(x) - g(y) \rvert + \lvert g(y) \rvert \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x) \rvert \underbrace{\lvert g(x) - g(y) \rvert}_{\rightarrow 0\text{ as }y \rightarrow x} + M \underbrace{\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert}_{\rightarrow 0\text{ as }y \rightarrow x} 
$$
This is continuity.
It is even easier to prove that the sum of continuous functions is continuous. Then, using the continuity of the identity and the above result, boom, every polynomial and every rational function is continuous (at points where there is no singularity). Then, if one wants to go further, one can extend the continuity of the polynomial to prove continuity of power series inside their radius of convergence. This gives you continuity for $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, $\log$ and similar elementary functions. Then, using continuity of $\exp$ and $\log$, you get continuity of all powers.
It might take a little more time to carefully establish all of that, but it would be ''more correct'' than just saying e.g. ''if you can draw the function without removing the pen from the paper, it is continuous''. And it would give a valuable intuition about limts. Try the latter e.g. for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $[-1, 1]\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (:.

"This gives you continuity for $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, $\log$ and similar elementary functions" - excuse me, what? How are you going to know that $\sin$ expands into a power series without previously showing that it is continuous, differentiable and smooth, and then using the Taylor's theorem and remainder estimation?

By defining $\sin(x) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \tfrac{x^{2k+1}(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Of course, you might have to prove and/or explain convergence. Then you get smoothness etc. . Or how would you define $\sin$?

I always thought that defining $\sin$ as a power series was a rather exotic and advanced approach, although formally convenient. I would rather define $\sin$ purely geometrically, locally sacrificing a little bit of rigour (because we don't want to strictly define things like arc length at this point), but retaining the very important intuitions about what the function really is. Especially when it is the student's first encounter with analysis.

Yes, that is a good point. I think that it is a balance: Either you introduce it by power series (which is a very abstract approach itself) and you get all the nice results "for free". Or you define it geometrically (which is intuitive) and you will have a ridicolously hard time to prove differentiability (no matter the rigour)

I don't get your point, proving differentiability of $\sin$ defined geometrically is rather easy. First we prove $\sin x < x < \tan x$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ by comparing areas. We use it to prove the continuity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ at $0$ and we derive the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. Using the trigonometric identities we prove the continuity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then compute the derivatives $(\sin x)' = \cos x$ and $(\cos x)' = - \sin x$.

How do you compute these derivatives? "Comparing areas" can of course be done, but is not too rigorous

It's still quite rigorous. But obviously when a notion is defined geometrically without laying down all geometry completely rigorously first, you need some not-so-rigorous arguments to get off the ground.

$$\begin{align*} (\sin x)' & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2 \sin \frac{h}{2} \cos \left( x+\frac{h}{2} \right)}{h} \[1ex] & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin \frac{h}{2}}{\frac{h}{2}} \cdot \cos \left( x + \frac{h}{2} \right) = \cos x, \end{align*}$$ the other derivative is similar.

I see, that is quite nice and I did not know it. If done right, this could also certainly be taught in a plastic and comprehensive way.

This is precisely how I was taught in high school.

I wish I would have been taught even this nicely…

The way to break out of this circular definition, of course, is to use the delta-epsilon definition of the limit to prove that $x^2$ is continuous at any point. And for any function that we want to evaluate the limit of by simply plugging in the approach value (Think $sin$, $cos$, $ln$, etc. basically every possible component of an elementary function), we need to first use the delta-epsilon definition of the limit to show where the function is continuous at and where it is discontinuous at.
However, I don't recall doing that when I took Calculus 1 about 6 years ago. I suppose that it would have taken too much time out of the class to do that for every function we had learned about so far. We would just take it at face value that certain functions were continuous at certain points and were discontinuous at other points, and then we would have the option to prove those claims for ourselves on our own time using the delta-epsilon definition of the limit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

One approach is as follows. You first define limits using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition, and then define continuity the way you did. When you substitute the number to find the limit, you know a priori that the function is continuous there (which is proved separately), and then it is justified. Most polynomials and combinations of trigonometric functions are continuous wherever they are well defined.
Hope this helps. :)
